# WPF c# displaying a image for a short period of time

Tags: c#, wpf, button, timer, click

I am trying to create a project where I have a picture button and once the user clicks on it the picture changes to something else.

But once it changes I want that picture to go away and go back to the original before it was clicked.

I am stuck at the point to create that "timer" for the second picture to show. Also the second picture that shows up is a random picture from 2 other pictures. So it needs to change pictures randomly after every button click.

Comment: What have you tried? What is your specific question? This sounds an awful lot like 'please program this for me' to me

Comment: My specific question is how can I display a random image for only about 2-3 seconds and have it go back to the original image? I've tried a bunch of random stuff from looking it up on the internet but nothing is the same as what I need. What I keep finding is how to make a timer in WPF. Which is not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Once idea that comes to mind is that you could try to use a BackgroundWorker implementation.

Click on Picture:

- Change the image to whatever you want
- Start the background worker

Background Worker Implementation:

- Thread.Join() for however long you want it keep that image
- return when done

Background Worker Task Completed:

- Set the image back to the original picture

It's not the true intent of the BackgroundWorker, but it will probably solve the problem you are trying to get around (not tying up the UI thread).

Comment: Well that is close, but when the user clicks on the image they dont choose what they want. Theres 3 random pictures that can be shown once the button is clicked. Would that still work with a random or no?

Comment: Yes, since the button click in the UI goes to the C# code, you can implement whatever logic you want at that point. Then start a background worker (which can take a parameter for what image to return to), and go about your merry way.